# Search and replace pattern - regular expressions pattern

Tags: regex

I am using a RegexRenamer in order to rename some files using regex match&replace;

Unfortunately, the tutorial didn't cover anything close to what I want to do and neither am I too good at understanding how regex works.
What I basically want to do is rename some files with the following pattern.

Artist, Name - song name

> Jackson, Michael - We are the world

The end result should be:

> Michael Jackson - We are the world.

I have a few exceptions for this rule for the featuring songs but the code for the first example will surely make my day after hours of googling.

Exception:

> Jackson, Michael & Akon - Hold my hand

should be

> Michael Jackson & Akon - Hold My Hand

Comment: At least the tutorial should tell you something about capturing group and backreference? You can capture the text matched by the regex and refer to them in the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(\w+),\s+(\w+)
```

With replacements:

```
$2 $1
```

[Live demo #1](http://regex101.com/r/bY4mQ3)

For multiple occurrences:

```
(?:(\w+),\s+(\w+))+
```

[Live demo #2](http://regex101.com/r/vQ6nC1)

If song name may have also comma `,` in it, then use this:

```
(\w+),\s+(\w+)(?=.*?-)
```

Comment: @ValentinDragan and also added another regex to avoid conflicts

Comment: This just doesn't work if there happen to be two names -- like `Jackson, Michael Andrew`.

Comment: @r3mus OP may clarify this then I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
^([\w -]+?),\s+([\w -]+)\s+([&\w ]+)?\s*-\s+(.*)$
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/pZ5fP6

Answer (score 0):

Regex is difficult, especially if you are new. Try this out:

```
Find: "([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z& ]*) \\- ([a-zA-Z ]+)\n"
         /\ group 1.  /\ group 2.   /\ 3.              /\ 4
Replace: "$2 $1 $3 - $4"
```

Note that some regex chars need to be escaped, and I escaped them with a double backslash as you would do in most programming languages. If yours only needs a single backslash, use a single backslash but note that you will need to replace \n with whatever the newline escape is.

Basically what this does is matches two comma separated alphabetic words, grouped in $1 and $2. `[a-zA-Z]+` means match one or more alphabetic characters. The parentheses make it capture whatever matches so we can put it in the replacement later. It swaps these names. Then it captures any extra stuff before the dash in $3 and appends that. This is just like group 1 and 2 except it also includes the & character and spaces, and it has * instead of +, so it matches 0 or more characters. (The extra part may or may not be there). Finally, it captures the song name in $4 and appends that. I assumed all song names only contain alphabetic characters and spaces. If your song names contain anything other that that, you will need to add it in.

DISCLAIMER: this regex is not tested, and may contain bugs.